# How many pairs of integers $x,y$ exists satisfy a equation $ax + by = d$.

Tags: number-theory

I am solving a programming problem where constraints are high $( 0\leq a,b,d\leq 1\times 10^9)$. How can I count all pairs $(x,y)$ given $a,b$ and $d$. $x$ and $y$ must be greater than or equals $0$.

Comment: What are the constraints on $x$ and $y$? There are infinitely many real and integral solutions to $x+y=0$, for instance. Also, please use MathJax to format your question.

Comment: x and y must be greater than or equals 0.

Comment: That doesn't really nail it down any further, the above comment has only one solution, but then increase the value of d and you get another line parallel to the first that now contains an infinite number of real number solutions. You should probably have more constraints. Are you counting on the limited number  of machine representable numbers?

Comment: @Triatticus:  OP should have said it, but $x,y$ must be nonnegative integers.

Comment: What is your time constraint?  Looping through a billion things doesn't take long.  Yes, there are much more efficient ways.  What have you tried?  If you have one solution, how can you find all the rest? -1

Comment: Time limit is just 1 second so looping through all possible x or y values is not working.

Comment: $10^9$? Is this another Project Euler or CodeChef contest question? You do know that we have a policy not to help users cheat in those?

Comment: @RossMillikan machine representable numbers don't have to be integers, but there are only a finite number of them in any given interval due to the nature of computers. All OP states is that the are nonnegative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming $a,b,d$ are integers, with at least one of $a,b$ non-zero. Then the set
$$ \{ ax+by: x,y \in \mathbb Z \} = g \mathbb Z, $$
where $g=\gcd(a,b)$. Note that $\gcd(n,0)=|n|$ for each $n \ne 0$. Thus, the equation
$$ ax+by = d $$
has a solution in integers $x,y$ if and only if $\gcd(a,b)=g \mid d$.

Suppose $ax_0+by_0=d$ for some integers $x_0,y_0$. If $ax+by=d$ for some integers $x,y$, then $ax+by=ax_0+by_0$, and so $a(x-x_0)=-b(y-y_0)$. Dividing both sides of the equation by $g=\gcd(a,b)$ gives

$$ \frac{a}{g}(x-x_0)=-\frac{b}{g}(y-y_0). $$

Hence, $\frac{b}{g}$ divides $\frac{a}{g}(x-x_0)$, and so also divides $x-x_0$ since $\gcd(\frac{a}{g},\frac{b}{g})=1$.

Set $x-x_0=\frac{b}{g}t$, $t \in \mathbb Z$. Substituting in the above equation gives $y-y_0=-\frac{a}{g}t$. Therefore,

$$ x = x_0+\frac{b}{g}t, \quad y = y_0-\frac{a}{g}t, \quad t \in \mathbb Z. $$

Conversely, it is easy to verify that $(x,y)=(x_0+\frac{b}{g}t,y_0-\frac{a}{g}t)$ is a solution to $ax+by=d$.

We have shown that (i) the equation $ax+by=d$ has integer solutions if and only if $\gcd(a,b) \mid d$, and (ii) if there is a solution, there are infinitely many. $\blacksquare$

If we wish to restrict our attention to finding the number of non-negative integer pairs, then that answer is always one of

$$ \left\lfloor \frac{d}{ab} \right\rfloor, \quad 1 + \left\lfloor \frac{d}{ab} \right\rfloor $$

provided we also assume $\gcd(a,b)=1$. This is not such a restriction because $(x,y)$ is a solution to $ax+by=d$ if and only if $(x,y)$ is a solution to $\frac{a}{g}x+\frac{b}{g}y=\frac{d}{g}$, where $g=\gcd(a,b)$. So we may assume $\gcd(a,b)=1$ in considering the equation $ax+by=d$.

There is an exact formula for the number of solutions too, but I will satisfy myself with simply showing that the answer is one of two consecutive integers.

Let me assume we are looking for solutions to $ax+by=d$, with $x,y$ non-negative integers, and where $\gcd(a,b)=1$. We'll also assume $a>0$ and $b>0$.

We know from the above discussion that all solutions to this are of the form

$$ x = x_0+bt, \quad y = y_0-at, \quad t \in \mathbb Z, $$

where $ax_0+by_0=d$.

Now $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$ together give

$$ -\frac{x_0}{b} \le t \le \frac{y_0}{a}. $$

Each solution $(x,y)$ corresponds to an integral value of $t$, so counting the number of integers in the interval $\big[-\frac{x_0}{b},\frac{y_0}{a}\big]$ is the count of the number of solutions $(x,y)$ with $x,y \in {\mathbb Z}_{\ge 0}$.

This is easily done. The length of the interval is

$$ \frac{y_0}{a}+\frac{x_0}{b} = \frac{ax_0+by_0}{ab} = \frac{d}{b}. $$

The number of integers in this interval must therefore be either of the two numbers in the claim. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Alright. I will modify my answer.